# FuelPHPでPOSTの配列を一括でValidationしたい

Tags: php, fuelphp

FuelPHPのValidaterで、POST送信された配列をチェックしたいです。 
以下のソースで送信処理をしましたが、show_errors()の表示が空欄になります。 
すみません、ご教授願います。

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" value=""> 
<input type="text" name="title[]" value=""> 
<input type="text" name="title[]" value="">
```

---

```
//入力値を取得
Session::set('inputs', Input::all());
$inputs = Session::get('inputs');
//バリデーションのインスタンス作成
$validate = Validation::forge();

foreach($inputs['title'] as $key =$value)
{
    $validate->add("title[$key]","[$value]番目のtitle") 
        ->add_rule('trim') //前後の空白を除去
        ->add_rule('required') //必須
        ->add_rule('max_length',50); //最大入力文字数
}
$validate->run();
//こフラッシュセッションが画面へ表示されない、空欄になります
Session::set_flash('error', $validate->show_errors());
```

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/36928　マルチポスト。

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/10057/tatsuyoshi-mizuno こちらのアカウントは？

Answer (score 1):

```
$validate->run()
```

の場合、POSTからデータをとりますので
セッション等から任意の値をバリデーションする場合は

```
$validate->run($inputs)
```

とします

または、配列データに任意のバリデーションをする場合
http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/classes/validation/validation.html#extending_validation
独自にバリデーションを作る方がいいかもしれません